# Reshuffle tensor according to other specific tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given certain tensors `a` and `b` where `b` is of type `uint` and `max(b) < len(a)`, I would like to get a tensor `c`:

```
c = a[b]
```

This would essentially reshuffle tensor `a` according to order given by `b`.

Comment: `c = tf.gather(a, b)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question - as per @jdehesa 's comment:

```
c = tf.gather(a, b)
```

This was exactly needed. Thanks @jdehesa!